# How can I combine the two array's, using the first array for keys and the second one for values?

Tags: jquery

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(dog, cat, fox);
```

How can I combine the two array's, using the first array for keys and the second one for values?

```
$array3 = array(1 => dog, 2 => cat, 4 => fox);
```

In php we have array_combine(); but I can't seem to find a good way to do this in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In js, unlike php, hashes and arrays are two different things.

So, I am assuming you want an object as final result instead of array.

```
var $array1 = array(1,2,3);
var $array2 = array(dog, cat, fox);
var obj = {};

for(var i=0,len=$array1.length; i < len ;i++) {
 obj[$array1[i]] = $array2[i];
}
```

Also, look [array_combine in js](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_combine/).

You'll find a lot of other js equivalents of php functions.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, use a loop:

```
var array3 = {};
$.each(array1, function(i) {
    array3[array1[i]] = array2[i];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop should do this just fine.

```
var arr1 = [3, 5, 7],       // keys, integers or "integer strings" e.g. "5"
    arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // values

var arr3 = [], i;

for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
    arr3[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
}

arr3; // [undefined × 3, "a", undefined × 1, "b", undefined × 1, "c"]
```

**Edit:** If you're using non-integers (e.g. not `1`, `2`, .. or `'1'`, `'2'`, ..) as keys then what you want to create in JavaScript isn't an *Array*, but an *Object* `myObj = {}`. An *Array* won't complain about adding keys like this because in JavaScript it inherits from *Object*, but it would be considered bad practice and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array3 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   array3[array1[i]] = array2[i];
}
```